# How to make a continuous line from non uniform 3d points?

Tags: graphics3d, geometry

I am trying to make a continuous line from a set of points in 3d. In general [`FindCurvePath`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/FindCurvePath.html) does the trick, but in this case, it is giving me disconnected lines.

```
(*data is given at the end of the question with 93 points*)
pts = SortBy[data[[All, 1 ;; 3]], Last];
cp = FindCurvePath[pts];
Graphics3D[{Red, Line[pts[[#]]] & /@ cp, Black, Point[pts]}]
```

[image]

How to make it continuous and a bit smoother if possible?

`Interpolation` is not working with the data. Perhaps there is some other trick.

```
data={{0.68,1.088,1.236,0.},{0.68,1.092,1.232,0.},{0.68,1.096,1.228,0.},{0.68,1.228,1.096,0.},{0.68,1.232,1.092,0.},{0.68,1.236,1.088,0.},{0.684,1.076,1.244,0.},{0.684,1.08,1.24,0.},{0.684,1.24,1.08,0.},{0.684,1.244,1.076,0.},{0.708,1.008,1.284,0.},{0.708,1.284,1.008,0.},{0.712,1.,1.288,0.},{0.712,1.004,1.284,0.},{0.712,1.284,1.004,0.},{0.712,1.288,1.,0.},{0.716,0.992,1.292,0.},{0.716,0.996,1.288,0.},{0.716,1.288,0.996,0.},{0.716,1.292,0.992,0.},{0.72,1.292,0.988,0.},{0.756,0.924,1.316,0.},{0.756,1.316,0.924,0.},{0.76,0.92,1.316,0.},{0.76,1.316,0.92,0.},{0.764,0.912,1.32,0.},{0.764,1.32,0.912,0.},{0.768,0.908,1.32,0.},{0.768,1.32,0.908,0.},{0.772,0.904,1.32,0.},{0.772,1.32,0.904,0.},{0.904,0.772,1.32,0.},{0.904,1.32,0.772,0.},{0.908,0.768,1.32,0.},{0.908,1.32,0.768,0.},{0.912,0.764,1.32,0.},{0.912,1.32,0.764,0.},{0.92,0.76,1.316,0.},{0.92,1.316,0.76,0.},{0.924,0.756,1.316,0.},{0.924,1.316,0.756,0.},{0.992,0.716,1.292,0.},{0.992,1.292,0.716,0.},{0.996,0.716,1.288,0.},{0.996,1.288,0.716,0.},{1.,0.712,1.288,0.},{1.,1.288,0.712,0.},{1.004,0.712,1.284,0.},{1.004,1.284,0.712,0.},{1.008,0.708,1.284,0.},{1.008,1.284,0.708,0.},{1.064,0.688,1.252,0.},{1.076,0.684,1.244,0.},{1.076,1.244,0.684,0.},{1.08,0.684,1.24,0.},{1.08,1.24,0.684,0.},{1.088,0.68,1.236,0.},{1.088,1.236,0.68,0.},{1.092,0.68,1.232,0.},{1.092,1.232,0.68,0.},{1.096,0.68,1.228,0.},{1.096,1.228,0.68,0.},{1.228,0.68,1.096,0.},{1.228,1.096,0.68,0.},{1.232,0.68,1.092,0.},{1.232,1.092,0.68,0.},{1.236,0.68,1.088,0.},{1.236,1.088,0.68,0.},{1.24,0.684,1.08,0.},{1.24,1.08,0.684,0.},{1.244,0.684,1.076,0.},{1.244,1.076,0.684,0.},{1.284,0.708,1.008,0.},{1.284,0.712,1.004,0.},{1.284,1.004,0.712,0.},{1.284,1.008,0.708,0.},{1.288,0.712,1.,0.},{1.288,0.716,0.996,0.},{1.288,0.996,0.716,0.},{1.288,1.,0.712,0.},{1.292,0.716,0.992,0.},{1.292,0.992,0.716,0.},{1.316,0.752,0.928,0.},{1.316,0.756,0.924,0.},{1.316,0.76,0.92,0.},{1.316,0.92,0.76,0.},{1.316,0.924,0.756,0.},{1.32,0.764,0.912,0.},{1.32,0.768,0.908,0.},{1.32,0.772,0.904,0.},{1.32,0.904,0.772,0.},{1.32,0.908,0.768,0.},{1.32,0.912,0.764,0.}}
```

Comment: Try `Graphics3D[Line[data[[Last[FindShortestTour[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]], 1 ;; 3]]]]`.

Comment: @J.M. great. Whenever you have time, put this into the answer. I want to accept something before I feel hungry again ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sometimes, when `FindCurvePath[]` gets ornery for a (supposedly) well-behaved set of points *in two dimensions*, I tend to use `FindShortestTour[]` instead.

However, the data in the OP has 3D points; thus, one idea (which worked OK here, but won't work in general) is to take a 2D "shadow" of the 3D points, and apply `FindShortestTour[]` to that shadow:

```
perm = Last[FindShortestTour[data[[All, 1 ;; 2]]]];
Graphics3D[GraphicsComplex[data[[All, 1 ;; 3]], Line[perm]]]
```

[image: rearranged points]

Comment: Thanks, @J.M. I just find out `FindCurvePath[]` can fail for a simple set like `{{2., 0., -1.}, {2., -1., 0.}, {2., 0., 1.}, {2., 1., 0.}, {2., 
  0., -1.}}` (MMA11.1, 10.4 Linux)